# Sometimes, just thinking about making it would suffice

Tags: style-manuals

I am doubting this sentence, and wonder if anyone has a pointer or two.

The context is, you don't necessarily need to make art...
Sometimes, just thinking about making it would suffice.
Sometimes, just thinking about making it will suffice.
Sometimes, just thinking about making it suffices.

To me, it sounds more correct to say, will suffice, as in it will do.
rather than, it would suffice, as in, it would be enough.
But, perhaps suffices, as in, it does the trick, is better?

Or maybe they are all correct in their own way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, they all okay.

Comment: Suggest *sometimes, it's enough just to think about making it*.

Comment: 'Situations sometimes arise where just thinking about making it would suffice.' Perhaps we don't even get to the planning stage though.

Comment: “Suffices” or even “is sufficient”

Comment: It depends a lot on what you want to convey. They're all grammatically correct but their meaning is slightly different